# Create BAK from MDF without SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a restricted environment without SQL Server Management Studio, only Visual Studio 2012, and a restricted internet connection.

I have a 50mb MDF file. I need to create a BAK file that I can use to restore a database on my hosting provider (it's the only option they have to create a database).

Is there a way I can create a BAK file from the MDF? Either by scripting through Visual Studio, or a small tool I can download to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `BACKUP DATABASE` t-sql command. Check the link below and scroll about halfway down the page, past the "Using Management Studio" section, for more detail on how to use the command:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx

Here's the sample from that page, in case the link ever goes dark:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
TO DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.Bak'
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups',
      NAME = 'Full Backup of AdventureWorks2012';
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try tonight. My work environment frustrates me - I get "An incompatible DacFx version is installed", and being restricted I can't update SSDT and DacFx :| Pain.

Comment: Check if `sqlcmd` is installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Osql
Or
Sqlcmd can be used to run
Sql backup database command